# Is it necessary to create mocks for all table classes in every PHPUnit test method in Zend Framework 2?

Tags: unit-testing, mocking, phpunit, zend-framework2

I have a complete running application and want to write tests for it. I've started by the `Application` module and I am following the [manual](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.1/en/tutorials/unittesting.html). Now I'm writing the "[first controller test](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.1/en/tutorials/unittesting.html#your-first-controller-test)" and as expected getting the error:

```
1) ApplicationTest\Controller\IndexControllerTest::testIndexActionCanBeAccessed
Zend\ServiceManager\Exception\ServiceNotFoundException: Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager::get was unable to fetch or create an instance for Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter
```

> The error says that the service manager can not create an instance of a database adapter for us. The database adapter is indirectly used by our `Album\Model\AlbumTable` to fetch the list of albums from the database.
>
> ...
>
> The best thing to do would be to mock out our `Album\Model\AlbumTable` class which retrieves the list of albums from the database.

When I'd follow the manual now, I'd have to create mocks for all / many tables of my application in for every test method or at least in every `setUp()`:

```
1) ApplicationTest\Controller\IndexControllerTest::testIndexActionCanBeAccessed
Zend\ServiceManager\Exception\ServiceNotFoundException: Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager::get was unable to fetch or create an instance for Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter

/path/to/project/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/ServiceManager/ServiceManager.php:456
/path/to/project/module/Catalog/Module.php:56
/path/to/project/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/ServiceManager/ServiceManager.php:737
/path/to/project/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/ServiceManager/ServiceManager.php:869
/path/to/project/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/ServiceManager/ServiceManager.php:494
/path/to/project/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/ServiceManager/ServiceManager.php:441
/path/to/project/module/Catalog/Module.php:51
/path/to/project/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/ServiceManager/ServiceManager.php:737
/path/to/project/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/ServiceManager/ServiceManager.php:869
/path/to/project/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/ServiceManager/ServiceManager.php:494
/path/to/project/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/ServiceManager/ServiceManager.php:441
/path/to/project/module/Cache/Module.php:58
/path/to/project/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/ServiceManager/ServiceManager.php:737
/path/to/project/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/ServiceManager/ServiceManager.php:869
/path/to/project/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/ServiceManager/ServiceManager.php:494
/path/to/project/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/ServiceManager/ServiceManager.php:441
/path/to/project/module/Search/Module.php:61
/path/to/project/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/ServiceManager/ServiceManager.php:737
/path/to/project/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/ServiceManager/ServiceManager.php:869
/path/to/project/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/ServiceManager/ServiceManager.php:494
/path/to/project/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/ServiceManager/ServiceManager.php:441
/path/to/project/module/Search/Module.php:81
/path/to/project/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/ServiceManager/ServiceManager.php:737
/path/to/project/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/ServiceManager/AbstractPluginManager.php:205
/path/to/project/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/ServiceManager/ServiceManager.php:494
/path/to/project/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/ServiceManager/ServiceManager.php:441
/path/to/project/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/ServiceManager/AbstractPluginManager.php:103
/path/to/project/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/View/Renderer/PhpRenderer.php:378
/path/to/project/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/View/Renderer/PhpRenderer.php:397
/path/to/project/module/Application/view/layout/layout.phtml:76
/path/to/project/module/Application/view/layout/layout.phtml:76
/path/to/project/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/View/Renderer/PhpRenderer.php:507
/path/to/project/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/View/View.php:205
/path/to/project/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/Mvc/View/Http/DefaultRenderingStrategy.php:126
/path/to/project/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/EventManager/EventManager.php:472
/path/to/project/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/EventManager/EventManager.php:207
/path/to/project/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/Mvc/View/Http/DefaultRenderingStrategy.php:136
/path/to/project/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/EventManager/EventManager.php:472
/path/to/project/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/EventManager/EventManager.php:207
/path/to/project/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/Mvc/Application.php:332
/path/to/project/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/Mvc/Application.php:307
/path/to/project/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/Test/PHPUnit/Controller/AbstractControllerTestCase.php:255
/path/to/project/module/Application/test/ApplicationTest/Controller/IndexControllerTest.php:41
```

Can it really be the recomended approach? Should I create mocks in one place and then "include" them somehow? Don't get, how to handle this in general.

Answer (score 0):

You create a mock of only the objects that you need to inject in that test.  In the example, you create a mock of a DbTable so that you are can control the database interaction and are not dependent on setting up any sort of database (making the test more brittle).

You would need to do this for any services that are required for testing a specific action in your controller.  Each of your actions should not be interacting with too many services so each test should only have a couple of mocks in it in order to be run.

Comment: A direct side effect of this will be to make you tend towards a more loosely coupled design, i.e. you will want design your software so there are minimum dependencies, so that you won't have to mock so many services. This is a good thing!

Comment: Thank you both for your replies! But what is with the approach recommended in the manual? Do I need to create mocks for all table classes in every PHPUnit test method, if I follow it?

Comment: No, you create mocks only for the ones that are used in that particular test.

Comment: How do I know, what ones are being used? I'm asking, because I'm currently getting the error I posted above even for an action, that is not using anything and hast no dependencies (or at least it seems so).

Comment: Without looking at the code, I would say that you have to be using an DBTable/Mapper somewhere in the action.  If you create a 'hello world' action with a test do you still get the error?